# How can I get Segment(line that connects two points) information in chartJS when hovering it?

Tags: chart.js

I need to get information about segment (ctx) in a line chart when hovering it and not the points in the dataset. The problem lies in the fact that chartJS does not provide a hover function for segments, but for points.

My chart is like a graphic representation of a geographic location so I cannot use the nearest interaction mode. I tried so many things to get the information when hovering only the line that connects two points. The only way I found was like this:

```
// CONFIG
 interaction: {
                mode: 'dataset', // 'nearest', 'point', 'index', 'x', 'y', 'dataset'
                // intersect: false;
                // axis: 'xy'
                // includeInvisible: false;
            },
 events: ['mousemove', 'click', 'mouseleave'],

 onHover: (event: any, activeElements: any, chart: any) => {
                this.mousePosition = { x: event.native.clientX, y: event.native.clientY };
                const canvasPosition = getRelativePosition(event, chart);

                const dataX = chart.scales.x.getValueForPixel(canvasPosition.x);
                const dataY = chart.scales.y.getValueForPixel(canvasPosition.y);
                let lineTouchingMouseOrUndefined: any;
                let hoverData: any;
                lineTouchingMouseOrUndefined = this.getLineIfTouchingMouse(chart, event.x, event.y);

                hoverData = { y: this.yLabelsMap[dataY], x: new Date(dataX), convoy:             lineTouchingMouseOrUndefined?.convoy };

                this.hoverEmitter.emit(hoverData)

                if (lineTouchingMouseOrUndefined.changedPoints) {
                    this.hadUpdates = true;
                }

                if (this.hadUpdates) {
                    clearTimeout(this.updateTimeout);
                    this.updateTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
                        chart.update();
                        this.hadUpdates = false;
                    }, this.updateThreshold)
                }

            }

//HELPER FUNCTIONS

 getLineIfTouchingMouse(chart: any, mouseX: any, mouseY: any) {
        let selectedLine: any;
        let convoyIndex;
        let indexPoint;
        let indexNextPoint;

        let removedSelectionFromOldPoint;
        let removedSelectionFromOldNextPoint;

        for (let i = 0; i < chart.data.datasets.length - 1; ++i) {
            let convoyPath = chart.data.datasets[i].data;

            for (let j = 1; j < convoyPath.length - 1; ++j) {
                let point = convoyPath[j - 1];
                let nextPoint = convoyPath[j];
                let convoy = convoyPath[j - 1].allData;


                if (this.previousSelectedPoint?.id == point.id) {
                    removedSelectionFromOldPoint = true
                }
                if (this.previousSelectedNextPoint?.id == nextPoint.id) {
                    removedSelectionFromOldNextPoint = true;
                }
                point.selected = false;
                nextPoint.selected = false;

                const closestY1 = this.extractKmFromY(this.getClosestYPoint(this.extractKmFromY(point.y), point.segmentId))
                const closestY2 = this.extractKmFromY(this.getClosestYPoint(this.extractKmFromY(nextPoint.y), nextPoint.segmentId))
                const y1labelIndex = this.yLabelsMap.findIndex(f => f.value == closestY1)
                const y2labelIndex = this.yLabelsMap.findIndex(f => f.value == closestY2)

                let line = {
                    x1: chart.scales.x.getPixelForValue(point.x),
                    x2: chart.scales.x.getPixelForValue(nextPoint.x),
                    y1: chart.scales.y.getPixelForValue(y1labelIndex),
                    y2: chart.scales.y.getPixelForValue(y2labelIndex),
                    point,
                    nextPoint
                }

                if (this.checkLineContainsMousePoint(mouseX, mouseY, line)) {
                    convoyIndex = i
                    indexPoint = j - 1;
                    indexNextPoint = j;
                    selectedLine = { line, convoy };
                }
            }
        }
        if (convoyIndex && indexPoint && indexNextPoint) { // when there was a hovered line
            if (this.previousSelectedPoint?.id == chart.data.datasets[convoyIndex].data[indexPoint].id) {
                removedSelectionFromOldPoint = false;
            }
            if (this.previousSelectedNextPoint?.id == chart.data.datasets[convoyIndex].data[indexNextPoint].id) {
                removedSelectionFromOldNextPoint = false;
            }

            if (removedSelectionFromOldPoint || removedSelectionFromOldNextPoint) {
                selectedLine.changedPoints = true
            } else {
                selectedLine.changedPoints = false
            }
            chart.data.datasets[convoyIndex].data[indexPoint].selected = true;
            chart.data.datasets[convoyIndex].data[indexNextPoint].selected = true;

            this.previousSelectedPoint = chart.data.datasets[convoyIndex].data[indexPoint]
            this.previousSelectedNextPoint = chart.data.datasets[convoyIndex].data[indexNextPoint]
        } else {
            selectedLine = {
                changedPoints: (this.previousSelectedNextPoint || this.previousSelectedPoint) ? true : false
            }
            this.previousSelectedNextPoint = null;
            this.previousSelectedPoint = null;
        }
        return selectedLine;
    }

    checkLineContainsMousePoint(mouseX: any, mouseY: any, line: any) {
        if (mouseX < line.x1 || mouseX > line.x2) {
            return false;
        }
        var linepoint = this.linepointNearestMouse(line, mouseX, mouseY);
        var dx = mouseX - linepoint.x;
        var dy = mouseY - linepoint.y;
        var distance = Math.abs(Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy));
        if (distance < 5) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    linepointNearestMouse(line: any, x: any, y: any) {
        var dx = line.x2 - line.x1;
        var dy = line.y2 - line.y1;
        var t = ((x - line.x1) * dx + (y - line.y1) * dy) / (dx * dx + dy * dy);
        var lineX = this.lerp(line.x1, line.x2, t);
        var lineY = this.lerp(line.y1, line.y2, t);
        return ({ x: lineX, y: lineY });
    }

    private lerp = function (a: any, b: any, x: any) { return (a + x * (b - a)); };
```

As I need to compute this many times due to hovering firing, and performance is going downhill.

Do you guys have a better way to get the segment element when hovering it and not just the points directly? Remember that I cannot use nearest because the blank space matters.

Image of final result. I know it doesn't show much, but I need to protect my company privacy:

[image: Image of final result. I know it doesn't show much, but I need to protect my company privacy:]

Comment: If you have sensitive data, you can create your [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) by using fake, possibly random data; it also helps that the code is simplified to exclude protected info.

Comment: On the issue itself, in chart.js it's like there are no line segments at all after the chart was drawn - there's no API for segments and since it uses canvas, segments are just pixels on the canvas. The code you show appears to be what one would do to detect mouse events over line segments; there's no radically different method. The code might be optimized by precomputing some parameters and eliminating some niceties, but that would require a full running example to test.